# Workqueue implementation in Linux Kernel

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, workqueue

Can any one help me to understand difference between below mentioned APIs in Linux kernel:

```
struct workqueue_struct *create_workqueue(const char *name); 
struct workqueue_struct *create_singlethread_workqueue(const char *name);
```

I had written sample modules, when I try to see them using `ps -aef`, both have created a workqueue, but I was not able to see any difference.

I have referred to http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-7-sect-6, and according to LDD3:

> If you use **create_workqueue**, you get a workqueue that has a **dedicated thread for each processor** on the system. In many cases, all those threads are simply overkill; if a single worker thread will suffice, create the workqueue with create_singlethread_workqueue instead.

But I was not able to see multiple worker threads (each for a processor).

Answer (score 2):

Workqueues have changed since LDD3 was written.

These two functions are actually macros:

```c
#define create_workqueue(name)                                          \
        alloc_workqueue("%s", WQ_MEM_RECLAIM, 1, (name))
#define create_singlethread_workqueue(name)                             \
        alloc_workqueue("%s", WQ_UNBOUND | WQ_MEM_RECLAIM, 1, (name))
```

The `alloc_workqueue` documentation says:

> Allocate a workqueue with the specified parameters.  For detailed
>   information on WQ_* flags, please refer to [Documentation/workqueue.txt](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/workqueue.txt).

That file is too big to quote entirely, but it says:

> `alloc_workqueue()` allocates a wq.  The original `create_*workqueue()`
>   functions are deprecated and scheduled for removal.
>   [...]
>   A wq no longer manages execution resources but serves as a domain for
>   forward progress guarantee, flush and work item attributes.

Answer (score -1):

```
if(singlethread){

    cwq = init_cpu_workqueue(wq, singlethread_cpu);
    err = create_workqueue_thread(cwq, singlethread_cpu);
    start_workqueue_thread(cwq, -1);

}else{

    list_add(&wq->list, &workqueues);
    for_each_possible_cpu(cpu) {    
                cwq = init_cpu_workqueue(wq, cpu);
                err = create_workqueue_thread(cwq, cpu);
                start_workqueue_thread(cwq, cpu);
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.